# Adding a custom font to the TinyMCE editor in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, tinymce

I'm trying to add a custom font I found squirreled to my TinyMCE editor in Wordpress.

I got the Font family dropdown to show up, but I can't seem to get my own custom font into there.

Comment: I hope this article will help you to make yours. - http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/05/how-to-add-google-webfonts-to-wordpress-tinymce-editor/

Answer (score 2):

You can load CSS. In TinyMCE settings:

```
content_css : "css/custom_content.css",
```

Than `custom_content.css` should contain `@font-face` like:

```
/* load a font */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Foo';
  src: local('Foo'), url('path/to/Foo.woff') format('woff');
}

h1 { font-family: 'Foo'; }
```

Comment: Loading the style works this way but by some reason, loading the font-face doesn't.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: You made me doubt my answer. But it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/okv8xq2w/ If you doubt that your font loads...than you can always include a style sheet hosted at Google Fonts CDN. Eg: `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Grand+Hotel);`

Answer (score 0):

**There are my setups in my Plugin (not in theme). This worked with Wordpress 4.9**

First, you need put you custom fonts to a folder. And linked them in a custom css file, you need to call full path in CSS. I my case, i put all my fonts in a folder `luc-nham/css/fonts` , then i call theme in CSS file. 
Note, in my case, my custom CSS file put into css folder and named custom_fonts.css, it will be use late.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iCielTALUHLA';
  src: url('http://localhost/lucnham/wp-content/plugins/luc-nham/css/fonts/fontsiCielTALUHLA.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('http://localhost/lucnham/wp-content/plugins/luc-nham/css/fonts/iCielTALUHLA.woff') format('woff'), url('http://localhost/lucnham/wp-content/plugins/luc-nham/css/fonts/iCielTALUHLA.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('http://localhost/lucnham/wp-content/plugins/luc-nham/css/fonts/iCielTALUHLA.svg#iCielTALUHLA') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/** Other fonts deracle same above */
```

Then you need some funtions in your main plugin file like below:

```
/**
 * Add fonts to TinyMCE select box
 */

function ln_custom_fonts_init( $init ) {
    $custom_fonts = "TALUHLA=iCielTALUHLA;" .
                    "Other fonts=Other fonts;" .
                    "Other fonts=Other fontst;" .
                    "Other fonts=Other fonts";
    $init['font_formats'] = $custom_fonts;
    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'ln_custom_fonts_init' );

/**
 * Register custom CSS file, it also affect if you call wp_edior in frontend pages
 */

function ln_custom_fonts_css( $mce_css ) {
    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';

    $mce_css .= plugins_url( 'css/custom_fonts.css', __FILE__ );

    return $mce_css;
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'ln_custom_fonts_css' );

/**
 * Apply font live show in backend (when creating, editing a post, page)
 */

function ln_admin_editor_fonts($hook) {
    if($hook != 'post-new.php') {
        return;
    }

    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url( 'css/custom_fonts.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ln_admin_editor_fonts' );
```